# Advice on Azure platform to host Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, data-warehouse

I am a Data Warehouse developer currently looking into using the Azure platform to host a new Data Warehouse.

My experience is with using on premise servers hosting standard SQL Server Databases, one for the staging database and one for the Data Warehouse. Typically I would use a combination of SSIS and stored procedures running in a scheduled SQL server agent job for the ETL.

How can I replicate this kind of setup within Azure? 
The storage size will be less than 1TB so could I just use Azure SQL Server Database over Azure SQL Data Warehouse?
If so would I need separate databases for staging and the data warehouse using the elastic pool option?
The data that I will be loading into staging will all be on premise. Will SSIS still be suitable for loading to Azure or will Azure Data Factory be a better fit?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, James, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Leon. Some great points here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leon has lots of good information there. But from a Data Warehouse perspective, I wouldn't use Data Sync for ETL purposes (mensioned as "not preferred" in the link Leon provided, [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data), in the list "When to use Data Sync").

For DW, Azure DB is a good option. Azure SQL Data Warehouse (known as Azure Synapse Analytics nowadays) is a heavy duty beast for handling DW. Are you really sure you need this kind of system with < 1Tb data? I'd personnally leave Azure Synaptics for now, and tried with Azure DB first. It's a LOT cheaper and you can upgrade later if necessary.

One thing to note about Azure DB though: Azure DB **doesn't** support queries over databases. That's not a deal breaker though, everything can be handled in the same database. I personally use a schema to differentiate staging from the DW (and of course I use other schemas in the DW as well). It's not very difficult to use separate databases of course, but the border between them is a lot deeper in Azure DB than on-premise SQL Server or other Azure solutions (Managed Instance for example).

SSIS is still an option, but the problem is, what you use to run the packages? There are options like:

- continue running them from on-premise (all the hard work is still done in the cloud)
- rent a VM with SQL Server from Azure, deploy the packages to the VM and run them from VM
- use Data Factory to run the SSIS packages

None of those are a perfect solution for every use case. First two options come with quite a heavy cost, if running SSIS is the only thing you need them for. Using Data Factory to run SSIS is a bit cumbersome at the moment, but it's an option anyway.

Data Factory itself is a good option as well (I haven't personally tried it, but I have heard good things about it). If you use Data Factory to run your SSIS, why not start using Data Factory without SSIS packages in the first place? Of course Data Factory has some limitations compared to SSIS which might be the reason, but if your SSIS packages are simple enough, why not give Data Factory a try.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using [Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview). It provides many price tier with difference storage for you. You can select the most suitable price tier for you. Azure SQL database also support scale up/down base on the usage.

Ref: [Service tiers in the DTU-based purchase model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu)

And as you said, the data that I will be loading into staging will all be on premise.

Azure SQL database has the feature [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) can help you do that:

Data Sync is useful in cases where data needs to be kept updated across several Azure SQL databases or SQL Server databases. Here are the main use cases for Data Sync:

- **Hybrid Data Synchronization**: With Data Sync, you can keep data
  synchronized between your on-premises databases and Azure SQL
  databases to enable hybrid applications. This capability may appeal
  to customers who are considering moving to the cloud and would like
  to put some of their application in Azure.
- **Distributed Applications**: In many cases, it's beneficial to separate
  different workloads across different databases. For example, if you
  have a large production database, but you also need to run a
  reporting or analytics workload on this data, it's helpful to have a
  second database for this additional workload. This approach minimizes
  the performance impact on your production workload. You can use Data
  Sync to keep these two databases synchronized.
- **Globally Distributed Applications**: Many businesses span several
  regions and even several countries/regions. To minimize network
  latency, it's best to have your data in a region close to you. With
  Data Sync, you can easily keep databases in regions around the world
  synchronized.

When you create the SQL database, you can migrate the schema or data to Azure with many tools, such as [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).

Then [Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync), it will help sync the data auto every 5 mins.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start on the less expensive options in Azure, go with a general purpose SQL database and an Azure Data Factory pipeline with a few activities.

### Dynamic Resource Scaling ETL

You can scale up the database by issuing an [alter database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#examples-1) statement and then move onto your stored proc based ETL.  I would even use a "master" proc to call the dimension and fact proc's to control the execution flow.  Then scale down the database with another alter database statement.  I even created my own stored proc to issue these scaling statements.

You also cannot predict when the scaling will be completed, so I have a wait activity.  You could be a little more nerdy with a loop that checks the service objective property and then proceeds when it is complete.  But it was just easier to wait for 10 minutes.  I have only been burnt a couple times when the scaling took longer.

Data Pipeline Activities:

1. Scale up, proceed if successful
2. Wait about 10 minutes, proceed always
3. Execute the ETL, proceed always
4. Scale down

### Elastic Query

You can query across databases with [vertical partition Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview).  Performance isn't great, and they don't recommend it for ETL, but it will work.  To improve performance try dumping any large table you need into a temp table and then transform the data locally.